# Tensorflow 2.3 doesn't find GPU

Tags: tensorflow, installation, gpu

For some reason my GPU is not used by tensorflow. When I run `tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()` it returns `False`. I have tensorflow-gpu installed, version 2.3. Also I installed CUDA 10.1 along with cuDNN 7.65 and have the correct environment variables.

When I ran `nvcc -V` in the console it verifies that my CUDA is release 10.1, V10.1.243

When I ran `nvidia-smi` it shows that my Driver version is 460.79 and the CUDA version is 11.2

Do I maybe need to downgrade my GPU driver?

Comment: Your `tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()` result seems rather conclusive that you are not using a GPU enabled version of TF.  You do not need to downgrade your GPU driver.  You pretty much *never* need to do that.

Comment: I tried uninstalling tensorflow and reinstalling tensorflow-gpu a couple times now. How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you share the logs that get displayed when you import tensorflow?

Comment: @ranka47 how do I get these logs?

Answer (score 0):

I too have the same problem, but when I installed PyTorch it correctly detected my GPU, previously `tf 2.1.0` was working fine.

Maybe it's a bug.

I will try to install `tf 2.1` and see whether it detects the GPU or not.

UPDATE 1/7/2021:
Tried installing the tf 2.1.0 version through conda installation but it didn't work.

Tensorflow was able to detect my gpu .I uninstalled the tf from `conda` installation and installed it through `pip` .I think the conda version doesn't detect the gpu.Make sure you the tensorflow version you are installing matches the requirement of the `CUDA` and `cudnn` library.

My current configuration:
`tensorflow-gpu`: 2.3.0

`CUDA`:7.6.5

`cudnn`:10.1